# How can I convert the Pathfinder construct crafting rules for my D&D 5E game?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-5e, crafting, conversion

I want to adapt the Pathfinder rules for crafting constructs to D&D 5e. (I'm a player and a DM.) I'm looking specifically at their iron cobras, shield guardian design, and extra golem variants, in regards to spells, money, and time required. Item-creation feats are also an issue for a conversion as well, since 5e has none.

Comment: This is *really* broad. It's not something that can be answered in under a page, and involves a huge amount of work to answer properly.

Comment: @Miniman You think this is broad, you have no idea. Also, I'm aware of that. You don't have to answer it fortunately

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just explaining the reason for my close vote.

Comment: Actually, this seems pretty easy to answer, although I can't be bothered to look up the spells. Basically, (1) find or make the corresponding spells in 5E, (2) set the rarity of the construct, I guess it'd be at least a Rare, (3) set the price, and finally (4) compute the no. of days as prescribed in the DMG. Feats are a non-issue because 5E doesn't need them. I'm guessing a PC will need at least two years to make one construct. ^_^